# Can a Chazan silently say Yom Kippur piyutim in English?

Tags: halacha, tefilla, yom-kippur, chazzan-prayer-leader, english

Some shuls (such as mine) do many sections of most piyutim silently. Is the Shat"z allowed to do the silent portions in English and just say the ending of the piyut aloud in Hebrew?

Comment: The piyutim are not actually necessary for chazarat hasha"tz, so I would assume that the quiet ones need not even be said, although I would be less sure about using English. The schul I was at this R"H was all but conservative in its trappings (it had a minimal mechitzah and used Artscroll rather than an RA approved machzor) they merely omitted many of the piyutim other than the responsive ones.

Comment: if something is meant to be prayed quietly in a certain nusach then it should remain quiet regardless of the language being used. there is nothing wrong with using English for davening especially if it is in a synagogue of which many of the members will benefit from doing so.

Comment: @NoachmiFrankfurt The same at my shul, even though it was pretty yeshivish.

Comment: Many of the piyutim are beautiful poetry in Hebrew with a very large number of references to other verses etc. I feel that an English translation would probably not do justice to them if used as a primary version (and not just as an aid to understanding)

Comment: @NoachmiFrankfurt While there are some shuls that do that, for the most part, you'll find it's because the congregants won't have patience to stay there the whole time. But among many, being that saying the piyutim is a minhag, they won't dare deviate from a minhag (if you want, I can explain the importance of a minhag)

Comment: @Epicentre Oh, I absolutely agree. The English translation almost always misses fine nuances.

Comment: @user613, I'm well aware of the importance of minhag. I agree that we should say piyutim, however I think that this is an alternate possibility. I'd just have the sha"tz say them quickly.

Comment: @NoachmiFrankfurt IIRC, Beurei Hatefilah stated that Sefardim never say piyutim as part of *Shemoneh Esreh*, since they consider this a *hefsek* (interruption(. Instead they say them before Shemoneh Esreh.

Comment: DanF, first of all, according to R' Jonathan Cohen's site on Sephardi minhagim says that the London Kehilla does say them https://sites.google.com/site/londonsephardiminhag/kabbalah-not . Second, they would still be creating a hefsek by inserting the piyutim before the amidah.