# Can a Shaliach Tzibur recite the High Holiday piyutim in English?

Tags: shemoneh-esrei, chazzan-prayer-leader, high-holidays

Some shuls (this seems common in non-Orthodox shuls) have a lot of English responsive reading during the High Holiday services.

Usually the "larger" piyutim, i.e., those that are recited while the ark is open are recited completely in English. The rabbi requests that the *Shaliach Tzibbur* (cantor) recites alternate verses in English.

Is there any halachic problem with the *shaliach tzibbur* reciting aloud these paragraphs in English?

What about any other parts of the *Chazarat Hashat"z* (repetition of the *Amidah*) such as *Kedusha* or the main brachot? Must these be said only in Hebrew or can they be recited aloud in English?

Comment: I cannot see an issue as most prayers can be done in any language. Reciting Kol Nidre in English may well be preferred as it's a declaration but that's not a piyut.

Comment: related http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/45855/759